# Making Saturdays and Sundays colorful

Tags: pine-script

I want to mark Saturdays and Sundays with red color background. However, it currently marks everything as red because my Saturday/Sunday check doesn't work.

```
//@version=4
study("Saturdays and Sundays", overlay = true)

isSaturdayOrSunday = dayofweek(timenow) == dayofweek.saturday or dayofweek(timenow) == dayofweek.sunday
bgcolor(isSaturdayOrSunday ? color.red : na, title = "Saturdays and Sundays")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, just found out that it had to be `dayofweek` and not `dayofweek(timenow)`. However, I will leave the question, because there weren't similar on SO, it might help someone else.

```
isSaturdayOrSunday = dayofweek == dayofweek.saturday or dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday

bgcolor(isSaturdayOrSunday ? color.new(color.red, 0) : na, title = "Saturdays and Sundays")
```